# Problems setting useState inside onClick handler

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I am using `useState` hook inside `onClick` handler to change and track the `focus` state. I set it to `false` initially and then change it to `true` and `false` several times in the handler. After each change, I do `console.log(focus)` and I expect it to be respective to the changes made.

```
    function App() {
       const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);

       return (
        <div
          className="App"
          onClick={() => {
          console.log(focus);
          setFocus(true);
          console.log(focus);
          setFocus(false);
          console.log(focus);
      }}
       >
           <h1>App</h1>
       </div>
     );
    }
```

In my case, in this code snippet, I expect to see in console `false`, `true` and then `false` again, but I see all of them `false`.

Why does it happen? I feel I am missing something quite fundamental here.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the state, the component will be re-rendered. State changes are not synchronous in nature. Try adding a console.log below your useState line and you'll see that it gets called every time you set the focus because the entire component is re-rendered.